# What does statement "abc: {..}" mean?

Tags: java, syntax

I have never come across such expression in Java. It is not even a switch case

```
 //no code above to make it look like a switch case or loop

 abc: {
    // do some stuff
      break abc;
 }
```

Do you have any idea what this does?

Comment: It's a [label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) followed by a block.

Comment: Looks like named block to be used with goto

Comment: @MartinPerry - Except that there is no `goto` in Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147821/labeled-statement-block-in-java

Comment: In the above code segment, `break abc;` will cause control to flow to the first statement following the `}` closing the block labeled "abc".  `continue abc;` would cause control to flow to the first statement in the so-labeled block.  (This is really only useful when you want to break/continue from several levels deep in a nested block structure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are labels, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
abc:
```

is a label and `{}` introduces a new scope for that *block*.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a label referring to the code enclosed by the block. This allows you to transfer the flow of the program with more control as opposed to something like breaking out of a while loop.